# Variables within lambda/LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

is there a way for bellow lambda expression to move the method call `ConvertFilterType(filter.FilterTypeId)` into a variable so it is not called repeatedly for every condition ?

This if statement is making sure collection consist of all required filters.

```
if (run.Filters.All(
           filter => (ConvertFilterType(filter.FilterTypeId) != FilterType.A)
                  && (ConvertFilterType(filter.FilterTypeId) != FilterType.B)
                  && (ConvertFilterType(filter.FilterTypeId) != FilterType.C)
                  && (ConvertFilterType(filter.FilterTypeId) != FilterType.D)
                  && (ConvertFilterType(filter.FilterTypeId) != FilterType.E)))
    {
       throw new ArgumentException();
    }
```

Comment: you can use `{ }` in a lambda expression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (run.Filters.All(
       filter => {
              FilterType t = ConvertFilterType(filter.FilterTypeId);
              return
              t != FilterType.A && t != FilterType.B && t != FilterType.C && t != FilterType.D && t != FilterType.E;                        
         }))
   {
    throw new ArgumentException();
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

King beat me to it.  Although it is not what you asked, I would also recommend that for improved readability, that you create a separate method with a more meaningful name.  This chain of logic can obscure the intent of what you are doing.  Extracting it into a method would help clarify the method's intent.  I would have put this in the comment's to King's post, but don't have the reputation yet.

Here is some sample code, though I don't know what the type of the items in your Filters collection to know what the parameter of the method would need to be.

```
   if (run.Filters.All(filter => { return IsFilterAllowed(filter); } )
   {
       throw new ArgumentException();
   }

    private bool IsFilterAllowed(FiltersItemType filter)
    {
        FilterType t = ConvertFilterType(filter.FilterTypeId);
        return
              t != FilterType.A &&
              t != FilterType.B &&
              t != FilterType.C &&
              t != FilterType.D &&
              t != FilterType.E;
    }
```

Comment: This is a very good point ! Thx. I am sure you will gain your reputation soon.

Comment: I just don't spend enough time on here contributing.

Answer (score 2):

King's answer is the way to go but could you could also do this it seems.

```
FilterType[] notTheseFilters = new FilterType[] { FilterType.A, FilterType.B...};
bool result = !Filters.Any(f =>
                    notTheseFilters.Contains(ConvertFilterType(f.FilterTypeId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If my logic serves me right, you could also do this

```
var filterTypesToAvoid = new[]{
     FilterType.A,
     FilterType.B,
     FilterType.C,
     FilterType.D,
     FilterType.E
};

if (run.Filters.All(
        filter => !filterTypesToAvoid.Contains(ConvertFilterType(filter.FilterTypeId))
    ))
    {
       throw new ArgumentException();
    }
```

This way there is no need for brackets in the LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

To extend what brader24 proposed, you could try :

```
 if (run.Filters.All(IsFilterAllowed))
 {
   throw new ArgumentException();
 }

private bool IsFilterAllowed(FiltersItemType filter)
{
    FilterType t = ConvertFilterType(filter.FilterTypeId);
    return
          t != FilterType.A &&
          t != FilterType.B &&
          t != FilterType.C &&
          t != FilterType.D &&
          t != FilterType.E;
}
```